# xamarin.forms bind listview-imagecell imagesource to byte[]

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I'm currently getting started with Xamarin.Forms. I have a ListView on my page, that I bind to my ViewModel. The ItemTemplate is of the type 'ImageCell'

There's no problem with binding the Text and Detail properties of the cell. However, I can't manage to bind the 'ImageSourceProperty'. This is imagesource is generated using a byte[] (My images are blobs in a SQLite database)

I was wondering if anyone knew how to solve this problem (or another way to bind a byte[]-image to a listview-item)

Here's some sourcecode:

```
var model = Graanziekten.Select(g => new OnkruidViewModel
            {
                Id = g.Id, Naam = g.Naam, Omschrijving = g.Omschrijving, Afbeelding = g.BitmapThumbnail
            }).ToList();

            var cell = new DataTemplate(typeof(ImageCell));
            cell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Naam");
            cell.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "Omschrijving");
            cell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "Afbeelding");

            var listview = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = model,
                ItemTemplate = cell
            };
```

the 'BitmapThumbnail' property is defined as:

```
public ImageSource BitmapThumbnail
        {
            get
            {
                //AfbeeldingSmall is a byte[]
                return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Afbeeldingen.First().AfbeeldingSmall));
            }
        }
```

If I use a dummy image (from a uri) it works fine. But if I use the code shown above, the contentpage isn't even rendered at all (empty black screen).

At first I thought the problem might have something to do with the fact the byte[] is fetched from the property dynamically, but the same effect occurs when I fetch all the necessary byte[]'s.

Also, when I add a single image to my contentpage, using the same method it DOES work. Just not in the listview.

I'm trying to do this on WinPhone8 (Although I don't think the platform matters)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding it to your List directly? Instead of loading that model-object.

```
    var cell = new DataTemplate(typeof(ImageCell));
    cell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "Afbeelding");
    cell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Naam");
    cell.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "Omschrijving");

    var listview = new ListView
    {
        ItemsSource = Graanziekten,
        ItemTemplate = cell
    };
```

---

You can also leave the Image property to this:

```
    public ImageSource BitmapThumbnail
    {
        get
        {
             return Afbeeldingen.First().AfbeeldingSmall;
        }
    }
```

And use a Converter along with it:

```
    public class ByteArrayToImageConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
            return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

If you'll use the converter, you'll need to change your SetBinding to:

```
    cell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "Afbeelding", BindingMode.OneWay, new ByteArrayToImageConverter());
```

**EDIT**:
Your SetBinding(TextCell) should be SetBinding(ImageCell).
Can you also try building the datatemplate like this? It shouldn't make a difference but I'm getting out of ideas:

```
var listview = new ListView
{
    ItemsSource = Graanziekten,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        ImageCell imageCell = new ImageCell();
        imageCell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, new Binding("Afbeelding", BindingMode.OneWay, new ByteArrayToImageConverter()));
        imageCell.SetBinding(ImageCell.TextProperty, "Naam");
        imageCell.SetBinding(ImageCell.DetailProperty, "Omschrijving");
        return imageCell;
    };
};
```

instead of

```
var listview = new ListView
{
    ItemsSource = Graanziekten,
    ItemTemplate = cell
};
```

Comment: I had to change that last line into: cell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, new Binding("Afbeelding", BindingMode.OneWay, new ByteArrayToImageConverter()));

However, it left me with blank screens (leaving out the image altogether does render the actual listview)

Comment: @PeterBrachwitz - Made an edit regarding the `DataTemplate`, I hope that helps.. Still making use of the converter.

Comment: Unfortunately, no difference. However, I tried adding a single image to my contentpage, using the byte array. It also didn't work; led to an exception. this is the trace:
Message "Invalid cross-thread access." 
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
Perhaps this functionality isn't properly supported in Forms' current version

Comment: Are you executing the code on a seperate thread? You most likely get that error by updating the UI while on a background thread.

Comment: Nope, all on the UI thread at this point. the byte[]'s are also in memory since the application start

Comment: No time to test it today anymore, but do you think it might be because the byte[] is inside the PCL project and not the wp8 project? When you load a imagesource from the assets, it's also in the wp8 project (althought fromUri makes no difference) ..just speculating

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem at all. It just looks like somehow a background thread gets started and is being used to update the UI.

Comment: So the problem is only Windows Phone 8 at the moment?

Comment: Apparently so. Haven't tested it on iOS.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem binding with FileImageSource.